# string in Request.Result is Truncated in MVC 5

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a WebApi Controller and a View which uses ajax to call that view.

Until yesterday everything worked great, but now, I ran the project, and the data transmitted is truncated.
Here is the example:

This is my AjAx Call:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(aoData);
oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": "POST",
    "url": sSource,
    "data": data,
    "success": fnCallback,
    "contentType": 'application/json'
});
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public object GetAllProductsForDataTable(DataTableRequestItem[] pRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

The data before sending it is correct. It's complete, but my controller receives a NULL value on the parameter so, I checked the Request data received and discovered that the json string is truncated. 
Something like this is what I get by calling **Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result** from the controller:

```
alue\":false},{\"name\":\"bSearchable_5\",\"value\":true}
```

The actual JSON value is much longer, but this is just the beggining of it so that you can see that it gets truncated.

Checking the length of the value is 1393 so i'm thinking it might be some issue with the length of it, but can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**

Checking the length of the truncated value, I see that is 369...
This should give some hint because total length of object minus the total length of the read values... is 1024...

Something must be making the request to be read from the char 1024

**UPDATE 2**

I changes the Controller Action to receive HttpRequestMessage instead of my object, and the Result using ReadAsStringAsync().Result returns the FULL string.
I'm guessing there is somethign wrong with parameter binding that MVC is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to reproduce this issue when I was providing JSON that could not be deserialized to the controller method parameter's type. If the Json cannot be parsed to the parameter type, the first 1024 characters of the payload are truncated when calling `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

In your case this means that the Json sent to you api does not match `DataTableRequestItem[]`. You should double check the JSON you send.

To figure out what your error is, you should check your Controller's `ModelState`. `ModelState.IsValid` is likely returning false. You can see the errors in `ModelState.Values`.

If you want to have a BadRequest returned when invalid JSON is provided on any api Controller without reaching the controller methods, you can add an `ActionFilterAttribute` as explained [in this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api#handling-validation-errors). This will make sure that your client gets the proper error message and prevent long debugging session to understand the obscure behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Even if the "client" part is not the same at all (no Ajax but kt/Android calls), I encountered the same issue and I confirm that the result of this code gave a truncated string:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [BasicAuthentication]
    public HttpResponseMessage Send([FromBody]string json)
    {
        string str = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The following code returns the full string

```
[HttpPost]
[BasicAuthentication]
public HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    string str = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this is happening? Having to do this seems like a dirty workaround